# Download link in browser / Open my activity if there is a special Content-Type in the Header

Tags: android, android-intent

The situation:

there is a website having downloads listed in this form:

http://www.xyz.org/download.php?id=1234568

The response header from the server looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2012 15:14:33 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny16
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myspecialfile.myx
Content-Length: 20269746
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Sep 2012 17:15:01 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/my+xyz+app
```

As you can see there is a special content-type application/my+xyz+app

How do i have to write the intent filter for my manifest-file that my activity is started so that i can handle the download?

this is what i have so far:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.Library"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"  android:mimeType="application/my+xyz+app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

According to another StackOverflow answer, the browser checks the Content-Disposition header and doesn't even check intent filters if it indicates an attachment.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770360/304876